# Syncing dm-crypted drives?

Tags: backup, encryption, rsync, dd, clone

I have 2 usb sticks, 8GB each:

```
usb1 = /dev/sdb
usb2 = /dev/sdc
```

usb1 is a full dm-crypted drive and I am currently using usb2 as a backup, just incase usb1 fails.  I am cloning usb1 to usb2 using the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc
```

This works as I have tested usb2 and everything seems intact.

What I don't like about this method is that it takes about an hour to run the dd command.

Once I have cloned usb1 once, is it possible to keep usb1 and usb2 in sync without having to clone the whole drive using dd each time a text file is changed?

Can I use something like rsync to sync 2 usb sticks which are fully dm-crypted drives?

I can dd usb1 to usb2 without decrypting usb1.  I'm hoping a solution exists where I don't have to decrypt both usb1 and 2 to sync them.  I'm hoping the sync program can figure out the differences at binary level?

Comment: USB (physical) ports come in pairs per channel. i.e. USB0&USB1, USB2&Usb3, etc. Have you tried connecting your sticks to different channels? i.e. connect your usb1 stick to USB0 port and the usb2 stick to USB2 port. This way reading and writing can be done simultaneously and you may see a significant increase in speed.

Comment: An hour to read and write 8GB? That is just over 2MB/sec. I would suggest using `hdparm -t` to test device speed, and possibly investing in some faster drives.

Comment: @bain, it's an old laptop, I think I am reading/writing 8GB over usb 1.0 ports.

Comment: What you want to do was implemented as a patch for rsync to add option `--copy-devices`, but this patch was never added to the upstream rsync source. Apparently the patch does still apply cleanly and it does work. See [Debian bug #509335 rsync: please build with support for '--copy-devices'](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=509335). You could use that but it would require recompiling rsync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block devices can be synchronized using [bdsync](http://bdsync.rolf-fokkens.nl/) — a fast block device synchronizing tool.
`bdsync` was built to do the only thing rsync isn’t able to do: synchronize block devices.

```
bdsync "bdsync -s" /dev/LOCDEV /dev/REMDEV > DEV.bdsync
```

This generates a diff DEV.rsync of the /dev/LOCDEV and the /dev/REMDEV devices which both are local.

```
bdsync --patch  DEV.bdsync /dev/DSTDEV
```

will make the devices synchronized.

Comment: This looks like that I was after.  I'm assuming I need to do the following instead? `bdsync --patch  /dev/sdb /dev/sdc` where sdb is the updated version and sdc is the one which is out of sync? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in code at patch. Fixed.

Comment: @oshirowanen, If you switch to file based partition from block based, there is another method which will save your synchronization time  40-99%. Are you interested on that ?

Answer (score 4):

## Alternative: ecryptfs

You should rather use a file-based encryption like ecryptfs instead of a block-based encryption solution in these cases.

Advantages:

- Given that you use the same passphrase for both devices, you can rsync your data even when ecryptfs is not mounted and save additional decryption and encryption overhead.
- You write only little more data than the payload, not a whole partition or container, which reduces wear on the memory cells.

Disadvantages:

- Filename encryption limits the filename length, if your filesystems allow for 255 *bytes*—like most modern filesystems including FAT and EXT—the limit would be 143 bytes. Be aware of multi-byte characters in filenames.

I heard that some people also use ecryptfs for online services like Dropbox or Google Drive.

## Usage

The Ubuntu installer uses ecryptfs to setup encryption of users home folders, so you may have already installed the `ecryptfs-utils` package. Using ecryptfs for external media is very simple, just execute the following command for the corresponding mountpoint:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs my_mountpoint/ my_mountpoint/
```

This will then prompt the following options and finally mount an additional layer to the *same* mountpoint or directory that encrypts and decrypts your data:

```
Passphrase: 
Select cipher: 
 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
Selection [aes]: 
Select key bytes: 
 1) 16
 2) 32
 3) 24
Selection [16]: 
Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: 
Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: y
Filename Encryption Key (FNEK) Signature [0000000000000000]: 
Attempting to mount with the following options:
  ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
  ecryptfs_fnek_sig=0000000000000000
  ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
  ecryptfs_cipher=aes
  ecryptfs_sig=0000000000000000
Mounted eCryptfs
```

If you use a password manager, you should save the summarized `ecryptfs_*` options along with the passphrase. Be sure to **enable filename encryption** (FNEK stands for filename encryption key).

## Tips for using ecryptfs

- **Finding long filenames**

  The following command should give you a list of files with filenames longer than 135 bytes (135 question marks if I'm not mistaken) and also works for multibyte characters.

  ```
  LC_ALL=C find . -type f -name '???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*'
  ```

  It's 135 because when you use rsync to transfer files it creates temporary files with a leading dot and 7 trailing characters (`.<my_original_filename>.abcdef`). If it can't create the temporary file it will complain and continue with the next file.
- **Working around long filenames**

  Use metadata where possible to include all the information you need or zip files with too long filenames.

  - I use the following pattern in puddletag to rename files:

    ```
    $left($num(%track%, 2) - %title%, 130)
    ```

    It's 130 because of the filename extensions. It does not currently work for multibyte characters, but I filed a bug on their bugtracker.
    like `.flac`.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the drives using lvm and then synch them with lvmsync. https://github.com/mpalmer/lvmsync